# new MongoDB\BSON\Regex search on text with apostrophe or parentheses

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to search my mongo collection field to match on strings, some of which have an apostrophe or parentheses like the title:

```
There's No Way out of Here
```

All my searches on strings without these characters work. How do I specify my code to match?

My code:

```
 $cursor = $collection->find(
    ['$and' => [
        [ 'recording.title'  =>  new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($title, 'i') ],            
        [ 'artist.name'       => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($artist, 'ig') ]

        ]
    ],
    ['projection'  => [
                        'recording'     => 1,
                        'release'       => 1,
                        'artist'        => 1,
                        'release-group' => 1
                     ],
    ['limit'      => 1 ]]
);
```

Any assistance with this would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using to escape these characters like

`$title = "There\'s No Way out of Here";`

You can write `PHP` code to escape all special characters in your query string.

Comment: turns out `preg_quote` does this quite nicely. Thanks.